# Multi-item carousel bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, carousel, bootstrap-4

I want to make a Carousel that contains multi items or images, it will display 4 items then when I press on next a new item will appear and so on.
This image describes what I want :

[image: Click to see the Image]

I've tried several codes on the Internet but all of them on bootstrap 3 and jquery. I want it with bootstrap 4 and jquery

I've tried [this code](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/QAmn5) but it didn't work

Comment: Check out this http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ it should do what you want.

Comment: maaaan thaaaaank you , you are really a life saver <3 <3

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Ill post as an answer. Maybe you can mark as answer

Comment: Maybe this solution helps you to fix your issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77640427/how-to-create-an-infinity-multi-item-image-carousel-touch-and-all-plain-vani/77640428#77640428

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out this kenwheeler.github.io/slick it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an **easier** solution using Bootstrap 4 only...

Add a special CSS class (ie:`active-next`) to show the items the same way the `active` class does. When the carousel updates the active slide, add the class to the next item(s). Then apply the special class only on larger widths using a media query.

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/Q26U8fJDbx

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-item.active-next {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#mySlider').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
  var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
  $e.removeClass('active-next');

  var $next = $e.next();
  if ($next.length===0){
      $next = $('.carousel-item').eq(0);
  }
  var $nextnext = $e.next().next();
  if ($nextnext.length===0){
      $nextnext = $('.carousel-item').eq(1);
  }
  $next.addClass('active-next');
  $nextnext.addClass('active-next');
});
```

[Demo Bootstrap 4](http://www.codeply.com/go/Q26U8fJDbx/bootstrap-4-slider)